# Django Queryset with custom property

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

django==3.0.5 django-filter==2.3.0 djongo==1.3.3 my database is mongodb
I have a simple model like below

```
class Parishioner(models.Model):

    def _age(self):
        return date.today().year - self.dob.year

    """Parishioner model"""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dob = models.DateField()
    age = property(_age)
    GENDER_CHOICES = [("Male", "Male"), ("Female", "Female"), ("Other", "Other")]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    mothers_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    baptism_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=baptism_certificates_image_file_path)
    marriage_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=marriage_certificates_image_file_path)
```

As you can see `age` is a calculated property.

I have my viewset like below

```
class ParishionerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parishioner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ParishionerSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        first_name = self.request.query_params.get('first_name')
        last_name = self.request.query_params.get('last_name')
        gender = self.request.query_params.get('gender')
        address = self.request.query_params.get('address')
        fathers_name = self.request.query_params.get('fathers_name')
        mothers_name = self.request.query_params.get('mothers_name')
        age = int(self.request.query_params.get('age'))
        queryset = self.queryset
        
        if first_name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(first_name__contains=first_name)
        if last_name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(last_name__contains=last_name)
        if gender:
            queryset = queryset.filter(gender__contains=gender)
        if address:
            queryset = queryset.filter(address__contains=address)
        if fathers_name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fathers_name__contains=fathers_name)
        if mothers_name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(mothers_name__contains=mothers_name)
        if age:
            queryset = queryset.filter(age__gte=age)
        return queryset.filter()
```

All I want is to return obects who has `age >= provides value`.
So if I send a request to this url `http://localhost:8000/api/parishioners/?age=32`
I'm getting this error --> `Cannot resolve keyword 'age' into field`

So how can I use this url `http://localhost:8000/api/parishioners/?age=32`
and get objects who has age greater than or equal to 32 ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function / property of the model in a query. You need to bring the logic of the function into the query instead.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear, Now

queryset = queryset.annotate(age=ExtractYear(Now()) - ExtractYear('dob')).filter(age__gte=age)
```

Comment: its giving me "subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a datetime_extract_sql() method" error

Comment: now its giving me "No exception message supplied"
Actual error is like this
The above exception ( Keyword: None Sub SQL: None FAILED SQL: SELECT "parishioner_parishioner"."id", "parishioner_parishioner"."first_name", "parishioner_parishioner"."last_name", "parishioner_parishioner"."dob", "parishioner_parishioner"."gender", "parishioner_parishioner"."address", "parishioner_parishioner"."fathers_name", "parishioner_parishioner"."mothers_name", "parishioner_parishioner"."baptism_certificate", "parishioner_parishioner"."marriage_certificate", (%(0)s - EXTRACT('year' FROM "parishioner_parishioner

Comment: @AMendis both options work for me, which version of Django are you using, or rather what database are you using?

Comment: django==3.0.5
django-filter==2.3.0
djongo==1.3.3
my database is mongodb

Comment: @AMendis It's an [issue](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/343) with Djongo not implementing the method. Although looking at the code in the repo it appears to have been resolved and the issue is not marked done yet, try updating djongo and see if it works.

Comment: just tried updating djongo. Still the same issue